# Can I read and write a FIFO from concurrent threads in .NET?

Tags: .net, multithreading, concurrency, queue, fifo

I'm using a `Queue<T>` for caching video. The idea is to fill it with data (`Enqueue`), start playing (`Dequeue`) and fill back continously as data arrives. Can I do the filling back part from a background thread?

Comment: What makes you think you can't?

Comment: Uhm, it's the same object, and I'm not aware of it's inner workings.

Comment: So your real question is if you need to lock it. If you can write the code and it compiles and runs, then you can do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for a producer/consumer queue. You can do this using `Queue<T>`, but you'll need to add locking to make sure you never access the queue from multiple threads concurrently.

If you're using .NET 4, Parallel Extensions makes this *much* easier with [`IProducerConsumerCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287147.aspx) and [`BlockingCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx) which do all the hard work for you.

Comment: @sztomi: Creating a producer/consumer queue isn't *too* hard using locks and Wait/Notify. It just takes a certain amount of care :)

Comment: Sure, I know that :). The question was about if I have to lock or not.  But it's good to know they implemented that in 4, even if I can't use it right now, so thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you can, if you lock access to the queue using lock() or using Monitor object.